# How to test if a motor's magnets are demagnetized?

Tags: motor, magnet

I have a motor in front of me which I'm fixing because a magnet came unglued. I was given it by someone else so it's unclear why the magnet glue failed. It could have been from heat, speed, or just a manufacturing defect.

Because the motor is of unknown origins and history, before reassembling it, I'd like to test that all the magnets are still good. What are some ways I could do this? I have access to some test equipment, such as an instron and oscilloscopes.

Comment: Magnets are pretty basic..... Have you tried sticking them to your fridge door?

Comment: Try rotating it at fixed speed and seeing how flat the DC voltage output is. If you have cyclical dips or peaks then the magnets may not be very well aligned or, some may have lost some of their magnetism.

Comment: With a weaker field, it should not only be weaker, but faster, too. "Ferrites" are more temperature resistant than NdFeB.

Comment: @Puffafish I value my fingers, these are not tiny magnets! They're from a 12kW motor.

Comment: @Andyaka that's a good idea. My concern is that a magnet or several could be damaged. I have no reason to suspect they are, but I also have no reason to expect they're not. Something obviously caused the glue joint to die, and it would be silly to blindly hope it wasn't heat.